# What is the basic concept (philosophy) behind the modelling of Nakagami-m fading wireless channel

Tags: wireless

I understand that that NAKAGAMI-m probability density functions that describes the random behavior of signal in a wireless channel.

But I am very confused about one thing, by what concept did these formula for fading channel came into existence. Because in schools and university all they teach is the formula and what it means, it doesn't explain how and why Rayleigh and Nakagami came up with this formula.

So I am asking for some resources (books article) that teaches the basic concept behind wireless channel modelling. How it was modeled, for example modelling of AWGN is well explained, so I am looking for explanation for Nakagami-m fading Rican Fading and Rayleigh fading. please help me

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

In science it is common practise to create models by **regression**. Nakagami fading was introduced when **empirical** results in mobile and urban/building environments showed to be distributed like a gamma function.

As far as I know there is no 'theory' why multipath fading in these environment *should* result in a gamma-like distribution.
I liked the explanation of [this site](http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr03/ricenaka/nakagami.htm), where it is usually correleated with the sum of multiple signals like in [Maximum Ratio Combining](http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr05/diversit/mrc.htm)